# Using Subqueries with joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get a list of customers that have booked country shows at our venue, however I cant seem to get the subquery and the IN filter right.

```
SELECT Customers.CustFirstName, Customers.CustLastName
FROM Customers 
WHERE Customers.CustomerID IN 
(SELECT  Engagements.CustomerID, Musical_Styles.StyleName
from Engagements
inner join Entertainers
ON engagements.EntertainerID = Entertainers.EntertainerID
inner join Entertainer_Styles
ON Entertainers.EntertainerID = Entertainer_Styles.EntertainerID
INNER JOIN Musical_Styles
ON Entertainer_Styles.StyleID = Musical_Styles.StyleID
WHERE Musical_Styles.StyleName = 'Country')
```

Comment: get rid of the Musical_Styles.StyleName in the inner select.

Comment: SQL server 2014

Comment: Don't have a subquery. Just join customers onto the end of the existing query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customers.customerid 
FROM   customers 
JOIN   
       ( 
                  select     engagements.customerid 
                  FROM       engagements 
                  INNER JOIN entertainers 
                  ON         engagements.entertainerid = entertainers.entertainerid 
                  INNER JOIN entertainer_styles 
                  ON         entertainers.entertainerid = entertainer_styles.entertainerid 
                  INNER JOIN musical_styles 
                  ON         entertainer_styles.styleid = musical_styles.styleid 
                  WHERE      musical_styles.stylename = 'Country') engagedcustomers 
ON     engagedcustomers.customerid = customers.customerid
```

Comment: The problem is there is no table named engagedcustomers :(

Comment: Still not working for me :/ why are we trying to join on a table 'engagedcustomers' that doesn't exist?

Comment: @NateEntleutner it is the alias given to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments your subquery has two columns which will not work because you are using IN. I would also highly recommend that you start using some aliases in your queries. It makes this a lot easier to read. Here is how your query would look using aliases and a single column in the subquery.

```
SELECT c.CustFirstName
    , c.CustLastName
FROM Customers c
WHERE c.CustomerID IN 
(
    SELECT  e.CustomerID
    from Engagements e
    inner join Entertainers et ON e.EntertainerID = et.EntertainerID
    inner join Entertainer_Styles es ON e.EntertainerID = es.EntertainerID
    INNER JOIN Musical_Styles ms ON es.StyleID = ms.StyleID
    WHERE ms.StyleName = 'Country'
)
```

Comment: I'm definitely a rookie so I appreciate all the input!